# How to duplicate table from table existing in excel

Tags: c#, .net, closedxml

I have an excel template and I need create new table based on existing tables following condition(s) for example month, year, etc.

[image: Table Illustration]

I'm using ClosedXML.Excel. How I can do it?

Thank you.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! ClosedXML documentation has [an example on copying cells](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Copying-Ranges). does it not what you need? let us know if you stuck on the code!

Comment: oh thank you because my company block github, I can not read this article